# Image Conversion for Unity Vuforia

Tags: image, unity-game-engine, vuforia

I want to reach my image target name in Unity 3D. How can I do this? Thank you.

Comment: Uhm...is this a programming question? Taken at face value, it sounds like all you need is an image editor like Photoshop or GIMP.

Comment: @Serlite I think he wants to programmatically convert his image to black and white then to jpg or png and send the image to Vuforia.

Comment: What format is your current image? Also post the current code you have.

Answer (score 0):

Use photoshop -> save for web function